# Azure DevOps pipeline set git user email from build variable

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

When pipeline is triggered by committer "Teppo Tulppu" "teppo.tulppu@duckburg" user.name ends up as Teppo.

Is this an Azure DevOps "feature" or can I fix this somehow?

```
  - task: Bash@3
    displayName: 'Set git config email & name'
    inputs:
      targetType: 'inline'
      script: |
        git config --global user.email $BUILD_REQUESTEDFOREMAIL
        git config --global user.name $BUILD_REQUESTEDFOR
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not the Azure DevOps feature. This is some limits with git config command. If your username like "aa bb", and you input the command like `git config --global user.name aa bb`,user.name will only display letters which are before the space.

So you can change your script to below and then the user name will display as your expected.

```
git config --global user.email $BUILD_REQUESTEDFOREMAIL
git config --global user.name "$BUILD_REQUESTEDFOR"
```

Just use the specifal characters `"` to contain the predefined variable can fix this.

Comment: Figured that out too, the small differences of my regular zsh terminal and bash played a cruel joke for me here.

On zsh you wouldn't need `"`.